# Running shell script in Azure Custom Data

Tags: azure, ansible, rhel7, user-data, azure-vm

Having an issue running a simple boot script for a RHEL 7.6 VM I'm creating in the Azure cloud. On the portal, I place the following in the cloud-init textbox under "Advanced":

```
  #!/bin/bash
  yum install -y package1 package2
```

I've also placed the same script in my ansible playbook:

```
azure_rm_virtualmachine:
  custom_data: |
    #!/bin/bash
    yum install -y package1 package2
```

In both cases, I can see that the custom_data made it over when I look at the <CustomData> section of the ovf-env.xml file, but there's zero indication in any of the logs that the system attempted to do anything with it. Any thoughts? This was such a breeze in AWS...

Comment: [The fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html#parameter-custom_data) says "Only used on Linux images with cloud-init enabled."; does that apply to you? Actually, kind of related to that: does your custom data trick work **without** using ansible?

Comment: RHEL 7.6 is on the list of supported images for cloud-init in Azure. Also from my general understanding, if the portal gives you the option to enter text in the cloud-init section when creating a VM, it should be supported. As for your second question, no I have not yet gotten it to work in ansible or the portal. However, all the documentation I've read thus far states that you should be able to enter in a shell script, just like you enter in script data for UserData in AWS

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, the issue seems to be isolated to RHEL 7.6. I've been able to get this to work on other images (RHEL 7.7, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, etc). I've escalated it with Microsoft, since they claim RHEL 7.6 should already be cloud-init ready.

The inline style I have in my original post DOES work in both ansible and the portal, so that's a relief at least. Don't see another working example of it anywhere else on the internet, so I'll leave this up.